# Facebook Messenger - No ring tone for calls

Tags: audio, calls, lenovo, facebook-messenger

I got a Lenovo Essential tablet. I have a problem that when someone call me via Facebook Messenger, the table only vibrates, it doesn't call any sound at all. But the sound for Facebook messenger's notification like - incoming inbox message, miss calls, still works. Looks like only the ring tone for calls is not working.

what I have tried that doesn't work:

- Clear data for Facebook messenger.
- Re-install Facebook messenger.
- In Facebook messenger -> Notifications & Sounds, I enabled everything.

I check [this article](https://forums.androidcentral.com/showthread.php?t=792882&p=5840187&viewfull=1#post5840187)

> Go to Settings-apps- messenger. In there will be an option
>   that says notifications. For some reason it was set to low priority
>   and silent. I changed it and it's been working perfectly

but I can't find any thing (I see "Show notifications" checkbox, but it has already been checked)
[image: Android Messenger Settings]
(sorry for the image's quality, I can't figure out how to take screenshot with this Lenovo Essential tablet)

So how can I enable ring tone for calls in Facebook Messenger?